# Iterating over xarray. DataArray first dimension and its coordinates

Tags: python, python-xarray

Suppose I have the following `DataArray`

```
arr = xarray.DataArray(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3),
                        dims=['A', 'B'],
                        coords=dict(A=['a0', 'a1'], 
                                    B=['b0', 'b1', 'b2']))
```

I want to iterate over the first dimension and do the following (of course I want to do something more complex than printing)

```
for coor in arr.A.values:
    print(coor, arr.sel(A=coor).values)
```

and get

```
a0 [0 1 2]
a1 [3 4 5]
```

I am new to `xarray`, so I was wondering whether there was some more natural way to achieve this, something like

```
for coor, sub_arr in arr.some_method():
    print(coor, sub_arr)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the DataArray - each element of the iterator will itself be a DataArray with a single value for the first coordinate:

```
for a in arr:
    print(a.A.item(), a.values)
```

prints

```
a0 [0 1 2]
a1 [3 4 5]
```

Note the use of the [`.item()`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.item.html) method to access the scalar value of the zero-dimensional array `a.A`.

To iterate over the second dimension, you can just transpose the data:

```
for b in arr.T: # or arr.transpose()
    print(b.B.item(), b.values)
```

prints

```
b0 [0 3]
b1 [1 4]
b2 [2 5]
```

For multidimensional data, you can move the dimension you want to iterate over to the first place using ellipsis:

```
for x in arr.transpose("B", ...):
    # x has one less dimension than arr, and x.B is a scalar
    do_stuff_with(x)
```

The [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/reshaping.html#reordering-dimensions) on reshaping and reorganizing data has further details.

Comment: That's kind of cool, but still kind of ugly and unintuitive. It's a shame that xarray doesn't have a more natural way of doing this.

Comment: I get an error when I do this: "ValueError: Ellipsis not found in array dimensions ('time', 'ens_member', 'station', 'lead_time')". My xarray version might be a little old perhaps?

Comment: To me, it makes sense that iterating over the array takes slices along the first dimension, I don't know what else it would do. Looks like support for transpose using ellipsis was added in [version 0.14.1](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/whats-new.html#v0-14-1-19-nov-2019).

Comment: Oh yeah the first dimension iteration is ok-ish, although I still think a bit ugly because xarray is generally more abstract than that, i.e. most of the time you shouldn't really need to care which dimension is in what order in the underlying array; certainly it is less readable in the code since that ordering is often non-obvious. The transpose version has the abstraction benefit, but is kind of ugly since you need to deal with all the dimensions rather than just the one you care about. I feel better using groupby, especially in older versions where the ellipsis bit doesn't work in transpose.

Answer (score 8):

It's an old question, but I find that using [`groupby`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.groupby.html) is cleaner and makes more intuitive sense to me than using transpose when you want to iterate some dimension other than the first:

```
for coor, sub_arr in arr.groupby('A'):
    print(coor)
    print(sub_arr)

a0
<xarray.DataArray (B: 3)>
array([0, 1, 2])
Coordinates:
  * B        (B) <U2 'b0' 'b1' 'b2'
    A        <U2 'a0'
a1
<xarray.DataArray (B: 3)>
array([3, 4, 5])
Coordinates:
  * B        (B) <U2 'b0' 'b1' 'b2'
    A        <U2 'a1'
```

Also it seems that older versions of xarray don't handle the ellipsis correctly (see mgunyho's answer), but groupby still works correctly.