How to use the result of a previous if statement to a next if?
I would like to use a while loop in Python for the following if statements. I dont know how to implement this correctly in python.
    if t == 0:
        za = ds.isel(time=t)
        abc = get_grids_inside_rad(127.2, 15.7)
        print(abc)
    if t == 1:
        za = ds.isel(time=t)
        ghi = get_grids_inside_rad(abc.lon,abc.lat)
        print(ghi)
    if t == 2:
        za = ds.isel(time=t)
        jkl = get_grids_inside_rad(ghi.lon,ghi.lat)
        print(jkl)
    if t == 3:
        za = ds.isel(time=t)
        mno = get_grids_inside_rad(jkl.lon,jkl.lat)
        print(mno)
    if t == 4:
        za = ds.isel(time=t)
        pqr = get_grids_inside_rad(mno.lon,ghi.lat)
        print(pqr)

I would like to:

use the output of the previous if statement (the first time step) as an input to the next if statement or loop it; and
save the final output to a csv file.

The get_grids_inside_rad(127.2, 15.7) is a function that reads lon and lat.
Currently, the output is like this. But I want is that there are four lat lon msl in the final output. This does not even print the output of the 2nd if statement.
      lon   lat       time           msl
17  127.5  15.0 2015-10-16  99847.414062

What is the best way to do this in Python? len(ds.time) is equal to 4.
Here's the full code for this:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
import csv
import sys


ds = xr.open_dataset('prmsl_koppu_oct16.nc')

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    # convert decimal degrees to radians
    lon1 = np.deg2rad(lon1)
    lon2 = np.deg2rad(lon2)
    lat1 = np.deg2rad(lat1)
    lat2 = np.deg2rad(lat2)

    # haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    r = 6371
    return c * r
    
def get_grids_inside_rad(ctr_lon, ctr_lat):
    lon = np.arange(0, 360, 1.25)
    lat = np.arange(-90, 90, 1.25)
                        # get coordinates of all points on the grid
    grid_lon, grid_lat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
    dists_in_km = haversine(grid_lon, grid_lat, ctr_lon, ctr_lat)
    dists_in_deg = dists_in_km / 111
                         # find nearby points
    thr = 2.0
    coordinates = []
    for i in range(grid_lon.shape[0]):
      for j in range(grid_lon.shape[1]):
            this_lon = grid_lon[i, j]
            this_lat = grid_lat[i, j]
            dist = dists_in_deg[i, j]
            if dist <= thr:
                df = pd.DataFrame({"lon":[this_lon],"lat":[this_lat],"dist":[dist]})
                coordinates.append(df)
                        
    xyz = pd.concat(coordinates)
    xyz.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    xyz.index = range(1, len(xyz)+1, 1)
      
    lat = list(xyz.iloc[:, 1])
    lon = list(xyz.iloc[:, 0])
      
    filtered_rad=za.sel(lat=lat, lon=lon, method='nearest')
      
    yyy=filtered_rad.sortby('lon')
    df = yyy.to_dataframe().reset_index().drop_duplicates()
    df = df[df["msl"]==df["msl"].min()]
    return df
    

t=0
while t < len(ds.time):
     if t == 0:
         za = ds.isel(time=t)
         abc = get_grids_inside_rad(127.2, 15.7)
         print(abc)
     if t == 1:
         za = ds.isel(time=t)
         ghi = get_grids_inside_rad(abc.lon,abc.lat)
         print(ghi)
     else: 
         break
t += 1

     

The ds has the following structure:

Here's the link to the data:
Link to the data

Please provide a [MRE]. The variable abc should already exist when the t==1 block runs, since you always encounter the t==0 condition before the t==1 condition. That you're getting only one output indicates that your loop never reaches the t==1 condition, which would indicate that len(ds.time) == 1

Even before that, can you confirm that t += 1 is inside the loop?

It's not clear why there is a while loop at all, if you're always using only using t==0 and  t==1.  Does the actual solution also use the other indexes instead of breaking?  Also, the t+=1 needs to be inside the loop.

in my example, I only showed t=0 and t=1, but it should loop through all timesteps of the file

@Lyndz The while loop shows nowhere in the "full code". Also, please make sure everything is indented correctly, the t += 1 should probably be inside the loop

@Gugu72 the while loop is the one that I dont know how to implement correctly

Consider this:
lon, lat = 127.2, 15.7

If you do that before the loop, things fall into place.
I am not going to download your dataset. For the future, please see How to make good reproducible pandas examples, but this should work:
lon, lat = 127.2, 15.7
t = 0
while t < len(ds.time):
    za = ds.isel(time=t)
    entry = get_grids_inside_rad(lon, lat)
    print(entry)
    lon, lat = entry.lon, entry.lat
    t += 1

Notice that in your code, instead of a chain of if/elifs, you have a bunch of independent if statements. As soon as t != 4 you break out of the loop. But even if you corrected that, your code would be an example of the dreaded loop-switch antipattern.

Original answer (based on original question):
You don't need a loop here, because you always want to do only 2 things, in the same order. That's just a sequence of statements.
(I assume za is a global variable used by get_grids_inside_rad? Try to avoid writing code that depends on hidden state like that.)
za = ds.isel(time=0)
abc = get_grids_inside_rad(127.2, 15.7)
print(abc)
za = ds.isel(time=1)
ghi = get_grids_inside_rad(abc.lon,abc.lat)
print(ghi)

Your original problem was that you break when t != 1, including when t == 0. You also only increment t after the loop has already ended.

Hi Jasmijn, wait let me edit my post..the code should iterate based on the length of ds.

"the code should iterate based on the length of ds": you start at t=0, go to t=1 (assuming the increment is inside the loop as I said in my comment above), and then break the loop. Why do you think there will be more iterations? @Lyndz

I editted my post @pho

@Jasmijn the first code snippet gives an error: IndexError: index 1444953600000000000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4.

In that case, ds.time does not behave like I thought it might, and you can discard that part of the answer. I'll edit it out.

Is this what you meant to write?
# Initialize parameters:
mydict = dict()
lon, lat  = 127.2, 15.7 # Initial lat/long

# Read through ds.time:
for t in range(len(ds.time.tolist())): # Need to convert to list
    za = ds.isel(time=t) # Does this need to be added to mydict? 
    mydict[t] = get_grids_inside_rad(lon, lat)
    lon, lat  = mydict[t].lon, mydict[t].lat
    print(mydict[t])
    # Option to add za to mydict (use *instead* of za = ds.isel(time=t)):
    # mydict[t]['za'] = ds.isel(time=t)

This would result in a dictionary with elements equivalent to your original variables as follows:
# mydict[0] == abc
# mydict[1] == ghi
# mydict[2] == jkl
# mydict[3] == mno

Reminder that int keys can only be initialized with {1:value} and not dict(1=value).  However they can be added after the dict is initialized with mydict[0], etc.
Edit: the documentation shows .tolist() should work with a 1D array as xarray is built off numpy arrays:
https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.CFTimeIndex.tolist.html

this gives an error: UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'less' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (<class 'numpy.dtypes.DateTime64DType'>, <class 'numpy.dtypes.Int64DType'>) -> None

Woops I meant for not while. Fixed it.

for t in? there's a syntax error. If I change it to for t in, this gives another error: ValueError: Length of values (144) does not match length of index (1)

I see that the ds actual structure is in the Question now, I will update my code to reflect this new information.

Thank you! I added the link to the data in the post. I dont know how to subset it and post the structure here.

I'm not sure if tolist() will work on an xarray, I read it as a np.array.  I'm seeing in other answers that you can iterate over the values directly though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971818/iterating-over-xarray-dataarray-first-dimension-and-its-coordinates
